# Projectile Motion (inclined to an axis)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

> A target is fixed on the top of a pole 13 metre high. A person standing at a distance of 50 metre from the pole is capable of projecting a stone with a velocity 10√g m/s. If he wants to strike the target in shortest possible time, at what angle should he project the stone?

I have attached images of the solution given in the book and my solution. Can someone tell me, what is wrong with the differentiation method? Where did I go wrong.(https://postimg.cc/gallery/3chd5vimq/)

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions. Can you try making a question about some concepts that you'd need to solve this problem?

Comment: I was solving the problem. Your strategy is fine. Problem: the derivation is wrong. Put t explicitly as a function of theta. You'll see something like $(...)^{1}{2}$ then "..." can be thought as a new  variable f. Corollary t depends on f(theta) and you have to use chain rule. If you do it you'll find very difficult to solve for theta; that's why the book used a different strategy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer santimirandarp. But I still have one doubt. Why is it necessary to take t as a function of theta explicitly?

Comment: @MahiDedhia No problem :); hmm no, I mean your idea was very good; but the derivation must be done very carefully...

Comment: @santimarandarp Disturbing you again but I went through my derivation once again and I couldn't find where is it wrong. By my method, I am still getting theta=45 degree which is not correct. Could you please spot the mistake.

Comment: In the equation written before taking the derivative, put $t$ explicitly as a function of $\theta$. (Im not saying you *need* but it is easier). You'll find something of this form $$t(\theta)=k\, (...)^\frac{1}{2}$$ Tell me if you find it.

Comment: Hi @santimarandarp. After pondering a lot over the qstn...I came to the conclusion that there are two functions which I am adding and then differentiating. This may be wrong because while adding some terms may change and ultimately give a different function. We need to substitute the two functions. But on substitution, we don't get any equation where theta and time are simultaneously present. So, we cannot differentiate t with respect to theta. That's why the book has used this method probably. I am pretty sure on this but just to be confirm, do u think the same?